# Chef rspec - How to handle open.file?

Tags: unit-testing, rspec, chef-infra

I have a chef-cookbook-recipe that uses ruby File.open:

```
File.open('/tmp/test.txt', 'r') do |file|
```

Without anything in the unit test it fails with:

```
expected no Exception, got #<Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /tmp/test.txt> with backtrace:
```

How do I handle it? I tried to find anything related to stub the file.open but everything, which wasn't much, didn't work for me. Maybe you can help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe something like this can help =>

```
before do
  allow(File).to receive(:open).and_return('the contents of the file')
end
```